# Only download audio from source mp4 link

Tags: audio, video, web, encoding, mp4

I want to be able to download just the audio track of an mp4 file from a source url, without actually having to first download the mp4 file and then extracting the audio. Is this possible? The motivation is that downloading the audio has much much smaller file size while downloading the video is a whole lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible. Just download the moov atom, looks at the chunks/chunk offsets for the audio track. Download those ranges and repackage into a suitable container for the codec.

Comment: thank you ! that's a great idea; I forgot of downloading it as a stream of data rather than as a whole file.